# Modelbinding from both body and route parameters web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a need whereby I am providing a model that contains all the parameters that I wish bound in a POST request.  However some of these parameters are coming from the Route and some from the body in the form of a JSON serialized string.

Is there a way in the WebApi to handle this so that i can just have the single object without needing to specify additional primative parameters.

so instead of this.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(int agencyId, string stockTypeKey, int stockClassId, [FromBody] ListingPostRequest request)
```

I'm looking for this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]ListingPostRequest request) 

public class ListingPostRequest : IRequest<ListingPostResponse>, IAgencyRequest
{
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }

    public string StockTypeKey { get; set; }

    public int StockClassId { get; set; }

    public ListingPostRequestApi Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is ambient route values, or hidden postback values as a fallback.  Have you tried either?

Comment: No, I'm not sure I know what you mean sorry

Comment: Ok, are agencyId, stockTypeKey and stockClassId properties of `ListingPostRequest`?

Comment: Sorry in my example I forgot to show that the object model is bound frombody.  Have updated

Comment: Ah, yeah you mentioned that but it's something I'm not familiar with so the subtly was lost on me.  I still don't know if your primitives are duplicated within `ListingPostRequest` and that makes it hard to answer.  It would be helpful if you could show that class.  But I think what you're looking for is not possible based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api under the headings Using [FromBody] and Type Converters.  Is that any help?

Comment: @Khyron thanks for your help.  Yes they are included in the object model

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `[FromBody]` and `[FromUri]` are basically instructions for the `DefaultModelBinder`.  It's a one-or-the-other proposition per parameter and what you're trying to do is have it dynamically chose for different properties of an complex object parameter.  Maybe it could be done by writing a custom model binder, but that's probably a bit more complex than what you were after.

Further information about model binding and the `[FromBody]` attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api